# Could u help solve the problem, why is it not summing in run thread?

Tags: java, timer

The variable `totalTime` doesn't change.
What can I do?

```
static volatile long totalTime = 0;

private void initTimer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            totalTime += 1000;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

This code reproduces my problem:

```java
public class Main {

    public static volatile long totalTime = 0;

    public static void main(String ... args){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                totalTime +=1000;
            }
        }, 1000);
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.println(totalTime);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Current output:

```
0
0
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
```

What I need to get this:

```
0
1000
2000
3000
...
```

Comment: And in my logcat always writes this:  D/Timer: 1000
D/Timer: 1000

Comment: Make the `totalTime` field `volatile`.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `totalTime` and how you're invoking it.

Comment: int score = 0;
    static volatile long totalTime = 0;
    boolean firstTime = true;

Comment: What relevance is `score` or `firstTime`?

Comment: if (Rect.intersects(birdRect, tubeTopRect) || (Rect.intersects(birdRect, tubeBottomRect))) {
                    if(firstTime || totalTime>=2000) {
//                        totalTime=0;
                        countOfLife--;
                        firstTime = false;
                    }
                        if(countOfLife == 0)
                            System.exit(1);
                }

Comment: @GameFusion Please edit your question to include the details being requested (ie don't post code in comments)

Comment: @Bohemian, i did it.

Comment: Andreas it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is you are calling the wrong version of `schedule`.

```
time.schedule(timerTask, delay)
```

executes the task *once* after the specified delay.
You want this version:

```
time.schedule(timerTask, delay, period)
```

which executes the task after the specified `delay`, *and* repeatedly executes the task thereafter every `period`.

Also, to get the output you want, you need to make sure the timings of the waking of the main thread and the timer thread are not too close, so you should offset them by initially sleeping half the period.

Try this:

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        totalTime += 1000;
    }
}, 1000, 1000);

try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(totalTime);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}
```